# Iterating through directories and removing files based off extensions in Python

Tags: python

I have a file structure that emulates the following:
[image]

I always have a folder, that folder contains an EXCEL folder and a bunch of text documents. Each EXCEL folder has a bunch of .xlsx files.

This same idea can be replicated an infinite amount of times following that same structure. I am trying to go into each EXCEL folder for each directory, remove all files with a .xlsx extension and continue this process until all the EXCEL folders have been visited.

This is a little bit of code I am failing with:

```
def clean_out_excel_test_data():
    #For each folder in the test_log directory
        #Open each folder
            #for each_folder that contains the word EXCEL
                #open each_folder
                    #for each file in each_folder, remove it

    log_directory = "test_log_data/"

    for each_folder in sorted(os.listdir(log_directory)):
        print each_folder + ' is in the root'
        for each_folder2 in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder))) if os.path.isdir(each_folder2):
            print '\t-' + each_folder2 + ' is a sub-folder'
            for each_excel_file in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder, each_folder2))):
                print '\t\t-' + each_excel_file + ' is a sub excel file'
```

I realize my code is garbage, but I wanted to at least show what I am going for.

Comment: What sort of trouble?

Comment: for each_folder2 in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder))) if os.path.isdir(each_folder2): is outputting as a syntax error for some reason. I only want to actually iterate through just the EXCEL folders.

Comment: That's because `for var in iterable if some condition` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Oh, is it possible to combine an if statement into a for loop?

Comment: Maybe easiest to do this in bash if available using a well-crafted `find` command.

Comment: @rern: No, it's not. I'd go with `os.walk()` as suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) handle the directory traversal for you:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/test_log_data'):
    if 'EXCEL' not in root:
        continue
    for fname in files:
        if fname.endswith('.xlsx'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, fname))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

you could do something like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(YOUR_BASE_DIR):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".xlsx"):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
```

The above will remove ALL xlsx file, regardless of what sub-directory they're in.  Should be easy enough to modify it to screen for directory name.

If you want to use `listdir()`, I'd recommend recursively walking a directory, adding all files to a queue, then iterate over it and remove the appropriate ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is coming from here:

```
for each_folder in sorted(os.listdir(log_directory)):
    print each_folder + ' is in the root' 
    for each_folder2 in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder))) if os.path.isdir(each_folder2):
        print '\t-' + each_folder2 + ' is a sub-folder' #                       ^ Here
        for each_excel_file in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder, each_folder2))):
            print '\t\t-' + each_excel_file + ' is a sub excel file'
```

You are trying to use a if statement in a for loop, you can't do that. Simply move the `if` into another block:

```
for each_folder in sorted(os.listdir(log_directory)):
    print each_folder + ' is in the root'
    for each_folder2 in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s' (log_directory,each_folder))): 
        if os.path.isdir(each_folder2):
            print '\t-' + each_folder2 + ' is a sub-folder'
            for each_excel_file in sorted(os.listdir('%s/%s/%s'%(log_directory,each_folder, each_folder2))):
                print '\t\t-' + each_excel_file + ' is a sub excel file'
```

It's still messy code, which could undoubtedly be done a better way, but that should get rid of your current error.

Steven Rumbalski's answer seems a bit neater though :)